# How can i Edit and save json data in a form Angular?

Tags: json, angular

now i have this object and i want make a form to edit this object values and save it so how can i do it ?

```
{
  "Get_200": {
    "Status_Code": 200,
    "MessageAr": "العمليه تمت بنجاح",
    "MessageEn": "The Process is Sucess",
    "Description": "when The Process of Display is Sucess"

  },
  "Save_201": {
    "Status_Code": 201,
    "MessageAr": "عمليه التعديل تمت بنجاح",
    "MessageEn": "The Process Add is Sucess",
    "Description": "when The Process of Add is Sucess"

  },
  "Update_202": {
    "Status_Code": 202,
    "MessageAr": "عمليه التعديل تمت بنجاح",
    "MessageEn": "The Process Update is Sucess",
    "Description": "when The Process of update is Sucess"

  },
  "Delete_203": {
    "Status_Code": 203,
    "MessageAr": "عمليه الحذف تمت بنجاح",
    "MessageEn": "The Process of delete is Sucess",
    "Description": "when The Process of delete is Sucess"

  }

}
```

expect solve this issue

Comment: Suggest you follow a basic tutorial as opposed to asking the community to do your work for you. SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: i want the idea of this problem not the code @WillAlexander

Comment: What do you mean by the "idea" of the problem?